# Google Collab sometimes not saving models

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm training a UNET for a project that I'm working for.

Usually, collab and drive works well and saves the models just fine. But, a handful of times, the model is not saved and I have to run that specific epoch again. I have no ideia why this is happening.

Am I doing something wrong with this code? (I'm not that experienced using Unets and training models in general, so please give me some tips)

```
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
                              filepath='drive/MyDrive/model.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.3f}.h5',
                              save_weights_only=True,
                              monitor='val_loss',
                              mode='min',
                              save_best_only=True,
                              save_freq= 'epoch'
                             )

resume_model_path = 'drive/MyDrive/model.12-0.145.h5'  

if os.path.exists(resume_model_path):
    model.load_weights(resume_model_path)
    loaded_weights = model.get_weights()
    if loaded_weights:
      print(f"Modelo carregado com sucesso a partir de {resume_model_path}")
    else:
      print("O arquivo de pesos do modelo não foi encontrado. Iniciando o treinamento a partir do início.")
else:
    print("O arquivo de pesos do modelo não foi encontrado. Iniciando o treinamento a partir do início.")

# Treine o modelo usando o gerador de lote para treinamento
model.fit(training_batch_generator,
          initial_epoch=12,
          epochs=100,
          callbacks=[model_checkpoint,],
          validation_data=val_batch_generator
         )
```

As seen in the code before, I always save the model and try to load it. But it's not saving the models everytime. It usually does save it, but sometimes it doesn't